# Angular directive within d3 SVG

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js, svg

Is it possible to include an Angular directive within a d3 `SVG`?

```
node.append("foreignObject")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .append("xhtml:my-directive")
```

`<my-directive></my-directive>` is created in the `SVG`, but the controller never runs and the directive's HTML content is missing. In a sibling of the `SVG`, the directive renders correctly.

Comment: you need to compile it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of AngularJS `1.3.0-rc.5`, you can specify your directive as an `SVG` by specifying `templateNamespace: 'svg'` alongside `replace: true`. Prior to this version, there was no real first-class support for `SVG` and you'll find yourself hacking around if unable to move up from `1.2.x`. You'll also need to inject and leverage the [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service to append a dynamic directive. Observe the following simplified example...

```
<svg id="mysvg">
    <rect height="100" width="100" fill="dodgerblue"></rect>
</svg>
```

---

```
.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $compile) {

    var node = angular.element(document.getElementById('mysvg'));
    node.append($compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')($scope))
})
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        templateNamespace: 'svg',
        template: '<rect height="10" width="100" fill="tomato"></rect>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log('linked');
        }
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/bovpkdzu/) - working demo v.1.3.0

You can also check out some [project discussion here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/7265) for the milestones of `SVG` support within the AngularJS project.